# How to indicate paired observations with lmer mixed models

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

I am fairly new to linear mixed models, and I'm trying to generate a model using `lmer` in which I test the effects of:

- Group (fixed): 2 levels
- Treatment (fixed): 2 levels (unstimulated and
  stimulated)
- Group * Treatment

on the dependent variable "Outcome", considering the random effect of "Subject".

In this experiment, each subject in the two groups had one arm stimulated and one unstimulated.

So far, the model I came up with is

```
lmer(Outcome ~ Group + Treatment + Group*Treatment + (1|Subject), REML=FALSE, data= data)
```

However, I'm not sure of how to specify that each subject has one arm unstimulated and one stimulated.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is more about an appropriate model specification for your case, I would say that it depends on your study and your goals. What you are describing is in line with your formula, and it makes sense as it is. You are already accounting for the Student effect with the (1|Student) and Treatment specifies the treated arm and the non treated arm. I would suggest you to check out [this post which discusses fixed and mixed effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)

Regarding the way of specifying models in lmer using formulas, my first comment is that the following 3 are equivalent:

1. Outcome ~ Group + Treatment + Group*Treatment
2. Outcome ~ Group + Treatment + Group:Treatment
3. Outcome ~ Group*Treatment

The third is a compact form of the second and the first is redundant. Then I would suggest you to try the following alternatives which are valid too, so that you get more familiar with the formula notation

```
model2 <- lmer(Outcome ~ Treatment +(1+Treatment|Group)+(1|Subject), REML=FALSE, data= data);coef(summary(model2));ranef(model2)
model3 <- lmer(Outcome ~ Treatment +(0+Treatment|Group)+(1|Subject), REML=FALSE, data= data);coef(summary(model3));ranef(model3)
model4 <- lmer(Outcome ~ Treatment +(1|Group)+(1|Subject), REML=FALSE, data= data);coef(summary(model4));ranef(model4)
```

Comment: Thank you JP, that's very useful